# C# / Microsoft SQL Server 2012: Unicode symbols not displaying correctly (•)

Tags: c#, html, sql, sql-server, unicode

I have a product database table on my SQL Server. I try to change its HTML text by my C# application. So far so good.

The HTML contains • - symbols for enumerations. Even though this • is being displayed in the SQL Server Management Studio it is not displayed in a web browser and not even if I reopen the product in my application.

If I update the product using the Management Studio by typing it in the table view (non-SQL) the • is displayed correctly across all applications. 
The table's collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS

I update the product like so:

```
UPDATE Products SET ShopText = '• 1<br /> • 2' WHERE ItemCode = '12345'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the *data type* of the column? is it varchar? or nvarchar? If you want to store unicode, you *really* want to use nvarchar... also: have you tried `ShopText = N'• 1<br /> • 2'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to place a `N` in front of your literal...

```
SELECT  '• 1<br /> • 2' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
      ,N'• 1<br /> • 2' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
```

**Important!**
Make sure, that your column `Products.ShopText` is a `NVARCHAR` (or `NCHAR`) column too...

### SQL Server knows two kinds of string:

- **Unicode UCS-2** (2-bytes, a subset of Unicode UTF-16), which is signed with an `N` at the beginning, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR` and `NTEXT` (deprecated), and literals with `N` like `N'SomeText'`
- and **extended ASCII** (1-byte).

Try this, it would work without the `N` (but **don't mix collations throughout your database!**):

```
SELECT '• 1<br /> • 2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

*Extended Ascii* uses the first 0-127 to encode the *plain latin set*. The upper part of the table is depending on the actual collation / codepage. With *1-byte-encoded strings* you cannot be sure, that the string remains unchanged:

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot for the quick response and explanation!